# Videos in jquery fancy box from local not in youtube

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I used fancyapps-fancyBox-v2.1.5-0-ge2248f4 plugin.If I use fancy box for youtube,it works fine.Its not working for videos from local.
I used a code like this,

```
<a class="fancybox"  href="pathToPlayer/jwplayer.swf?file=video/php.mp4&autostart=true" title="local video mp4"> 
      <img class="trigger" src="images/22.jpg" alt="" style="margin:16px 16px 19px 0px;" /></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".fancybox").on("click", function(){
        $.fancybox({
          href: this.href,
          type: $(this).data("type")
        }); // fancybox
        return false   
    }); // on
});
    </script>
```

By using this,I got popup but the video doesn't display.

Comment: open Inspect element : => what u get here as href ?? `<a class="fancybox"  href="pathToPlayer`

Comment: Can u check using `<a class="fancybox" data-type="swf" href="pathToPlayer/jwplayer.swf?file=pathToVideo/video.mp4&autostart=true" title="local video mp4">open local video</a>`

Comment: I tried this too..but it doesn't works

Comment: why dont u use <video> tag of html ?

Comment: and put it inside a div or iframe

Comment: Do u have WAMP server or IIS server started ? What is extension of the file you are running ? .html?

Comment: You may be interested in using [mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) (MEJS) to play your videos in fancybox. Check http://www.picssel.com/play-mp4-videos-with-mediaelement-js-in-fancybox/